# Multiple Cell Images

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

Can you place more than one image in a UITableViewCell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard UITableViewCell only supports one image (via the imageView.image property).

However, you can make a custom subclass of UITableViewCell and add the desired number of image views.

Comment: OK.  I'll look for a tutorial on doing that.

Thanks.

Comment: It is discussed in *iPhone SDK Development* by Bill Dudney and Chris Adamson available from the Pragmatic Bookshelf: http://www.pragprog.com/titles/amiphd/iphone-sdk-development

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can have 2 images per cell, without customizing.

1. imageView
2. accessoryView

You can also add images to the contentView.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to set a custom view (with any number of images) as the cell's `contentView`.

You could create a custom view and set it as the cell's `contentView` property. Apple´s [Table View Programming Guide for iPhone OS](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18) explains in good detail possible strategies for customization of an `UITableViewCell`.